# Group by a column, another column concatenate

Tags: python, pandas

For the following dataframe,

```
d = {'col1': [33,33,33,34,34,34], 'col2': ["hello","hello1","hello2","hello3","hello4","hello5"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(d)
```

I want it to group by `col1` and the content in `col2` are concatenate as a list, the result is as followed:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [33,34], 'col2': [["hello","hello1","hello2"],["hello3","hello4","hello5"]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(d)
```

Is there an easy way to achieve that?

Comment: It is dupe :( `print (df.groupby('col1')['col2'].apply(list).reset_index())`

Comment: @jezrael thanks, but now it looks like `0     [[hello, hello1, hello2]]
1    [[hello3, hello4, hello5]]`
each line has two lists [[..]], ideally should be 1 [..], how should we make it as such?

Comment: What is expected output? I check solution in commnet convert to dict `print (df.groupby('col1')['col2'].apply(list).reset_index().to_dict('list'))` and this is exactly what you need. Or something missing?

Comment: @jezrael, the output in the first comment is given this:
`d = {'col1': [33, 34], 'col2': [[["hello", "hello1", "hello2"]], [["hello3", "hello4", "hello5"]]]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    print(df)`

The expected one is given in the question.

Comment: Do you use first DataFrame as input? `d = {'col1': [33,33,33,34,34,34], 'col2': ["hello","hello1","hello2","hello3","hello4","hello5"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)` ?

Comment: @jezrael you  are right! thanks!